# How to connect Firebase with C# from a Windows 10 Universal app?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, firebase-realtime-database, windows-10-universal

There isn't much documentation related to using Firebase with C# in .NET.

I have a project on Firebase and I want to connect and authenticate to Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

If webforms of VS, I believe that you can to use **Firebase Documentation for Web 
 Platform**: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup?hl=pt-br